Serverside dynamically addClass Datatables
NOTE - Datatable serverside processing with MySql database
and the code is as follows

$(document).ready(function(){
 var table = $('#userDataList').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "fetchData.php",
        stateSave: 'true'
    });
});


Also the table / page available at
http://testlearn.infinityfreeapp.com/index-old.html
How to add a class to all
a) even rows dynamically.
b) odd columns dynamically.
(with or without a button click)

Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question in plain English. Also note that you're expected to make an attempt and show your effort.

You can do this using rowCallback() on datatable initialisation.
$(document).ready(function () {
  var table = $("#userDataList").DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: "fetchData.php",
    stateSave: "true",
    rowCallback: function (row, data, index) {
      if (index % 2 == 0) {
        $(row).addClass("oddRow");
      } else {
        $(row).addClass("evenRow");
      }
    },
  });
});

Use this CSS to see the difference
table.dataTable tbody tr.evenRow{
    background-color: green;
}
table.dataTable tbody tr.oddRow{
    background-color: red;
}

Demo

Yuvaraj M - cheers.

Yuvaraj M - did it.

Yuvaraj M - cheers

Yuvaraj M - I don't know how to add separate class to each header cell. Did you know that ? If 'YES' can you share with me ?

so you want unique class names for each headers right ?

https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.className check out this

possible to do it with css ?

could you create another question for that ?

unable to create any more questions that was informed by stackoverflow. No problem leave it. cheers
